# Read from text file and assign data to new variable

Tags: file, variables, python-3.x

Python 3 program allows people to choose from list of employee names.
Data held on text file look like this:   **('larry', 3, 100)**
(being the persons name, weeks worked and payment)

I need a way to assign each part of the text file to a new variable, 
so that the user can enter a new amount of weeks and the program calculates the new payment.

Below is my code and attempt at figuring it out.

```
import os
choices = [f for f in os.listdir(os.curdir) if f.endswith(".txt")]
print (choices)
emp_choice = input("choose an employee:")

file = open(emp_choice + ".txt")

data = file.readlines()
name = data[0]
weeks_worked = data[1]
weekly_payment= data[2]

new_weeks = int(input ("Enter new number of weeks"))
new_payment = new_weeks * weekly_payment
print (name + "will now be paid" + str(new_payment))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

currently you are assigning the first three lines form the file to `name`, `weeks_worked` and `weekly_payment`.  but what you want (i think) is to separate a single line, formatted as `('larry', 3, 100)` (does each file have only one line?).

so you probably want code like:

```
from re import compile

# your code to choose file

line_format = compile(r"\s*\(\s*'([^']*)'\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*\)")
file = open(emp_choice + ".txt")
line = file.readline()   # read the first line only
match = line_format.match(line)
if match:
    name, weeks_worked, weekly_payment = match.groups()
else:
    raise Exception('Could not match %s' % line)

# your code to update information
```

the regular expression looks complicated, but is really quite simple:

```
\(...\)  matches the parentheses in the line
\s*      matches optional spaces (it's not clear to me if you have spaces or not
         in various places between words, so this matches just in case)
\d+      matches a number (1 or more digits)
[^']*    matches anything except a quote (so matches the name)
(...)    (without the \ backslashes) indicates a group that you want to read 
         afterwards by calling .groups()
```

and these are built from simpler parts (like `*` and `+` and `\d`) which are described at http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

if you want to repeat this for many lines, you probably want something like:

```
name, weeks_worked, weekly_payment = [], [], []
for line in file.readlines():
    match = line_format.match(line)
    if match:
        name.append(match.group(1))
        weeks_worked.append(match.group(2))
        weekly_payment.append(match.group(3))
    else:
        raise ...
```

Comment: Is there not a way have a for loop that looks at each element in the text file and assign a index number to it. Then my variables can match the index numbers?